# SQL WHERE CASE Check hash values

Tags: sql, hash, case, where-clause, case-when

I am trying to create a CASE where I can check for a unique hash value that will set a new owner depending on which hash value matches during ticket creation. Here is what I have currently:

```
 Select DISTINCT HD_TICKET.*, USER
 FROM HD_TICKET
 Where  
   CASE 
    WHEN HD_STATUS_ID = 1 AND HD_TICKET.TITLE LIKE '%#:020:#%' THEN
    UPDATE HD_TICKET, USER 
    SET HD_TICKET.Owner_ID = USER.ID
    WHERE USER.ID = '1234'

   WHEN HD_STATUS_ID = 1 AND HD_TICKET.TITLE LIKE '%#:030:#%' THEN
    UPDATE HD_TICKET, USER 
    SET HD_TICKET.Owner_ID = USER.ID
    WHERE USER.ID = '1235'

   WHEN HD_STATUS_ID = 1 AND HD_TICKET.TITLE LIKE '%#:040:#%' THEN
    UPDATE HD_TICKET, USER 
    SET HD_TICKET.Owner_ID = USER.ID
    WHERE USER.ID = '1236'

    WHEN HD_STATUS_ID = 1 AND HD_TICKET.TITLE LIKE '%#:050:#%' THEN
    UPDATE HD_TICKET, USER 
    SET HD_TICKET.Owner_ID = USER.ID
    WHERE USER.ID = '1237'

    WHEN HD_STATUS_ID = 1 AND HD_TICKET.TITLE LIKE '%#:060:#%' THEN
    UPDATE HD_TICKET, USER 
    SET HD_TICKET.Owner_ID = USER.ID
    WHERE USER.ID = '1238'

    WHEN HD_STATUS_ID = 1 AND HD_TICKET.TITLE LIKE '%#:070:#%' THEN
    UPDATE HD_TICKET, USER 
    SET HD_TICKET.Owner_ID = USER.ID
    WHERE USER.ID = '1239'

    WHEN HD_STATUS_ID = 1 AND HD_TICKET.TITLE LIKE '%#:080:#%' THEN
    UPDATE HD_TICKET, USER 
    SET HD_TICKET.Owner_ID = USER.ID
    WHERE USER.ID = '1240'
END
```

Comment: You can't embed update statements inside a where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simplify (and simplify again). This should give you what you're after:

```
update hd_ticket
set hd.owner_id = case
                    when hd.title like '%#:020:#%' THEN '1234'
                    when hd.title like '%#:030:#%' THEN '1235'
                    when hd.title like '%#:040:#%' THEN '1236'
                    when hd.title like '%#:050:#%' THEN '1237'
                    when hd.title like '%#:060:#%' THEN '1238'
                    when hd.title like '%#:070:#%' THEN '1239'
                    when hd.title like '%#:080:#%' THEN '1240'
                  end
from hd_ticket hd
where hd.hd_status_id =    1
  and hd.title        like '%#:0[2345678]0:#%'
```

If your Sql implementation doesn't support character classes as wildcards, you'll need to do something like this:

```
where hd.hd_status_id =    1
  and (    hd.title like '%#:020:#%'
        OR hd.title like '%#:030:#%'
        OR hd.title like '%#:040:#%'
        OR hd.title like '%#:050:#%'
        OR hd.title like '%#:060:#%'
        OR hd.title like '%#:070:#%'
        OR hd.title like '%#:080:#%'
      )
```

If you're SQL implementation supports regular expression (like Oracle) then you could use a regular expression to be much more concise.

Comment: It doesn't like the Array inside the LIKE statement. 
I tried the following Concatenation but it doesn't like this either:
    Where  HD_STATUS_ID = 1 AND HD_TICKET.TITLE LIKE '%#:0' +     [2345678] + '0:#%'

Comment: It's not an array: it's a *character class*. See my amended answer for alternatives.

Comment: Thank you!! Just going to need to tweak a few things on top of that to finish up what I am doing.  What I am trying to do is generate an email if to a specific group depending on the hash values. So I am searching for for the hash upon saving the ticket, checking that ticket against these values and setting it to the correct department.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Merge instead:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

You match on criteria and choose to do something when matched or not matched etc... you can also save or return the results.